# HTTP ERROR 500 After Migration in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

I recently migrated my staging site into the live site using All in One WP Migration plugin. After migration, I am getting an HTTP Error 500. Here is the error log

> Fatal error: Class 'ET_Core_API_Email_Fields' not found in /home/mashbrewing/public_html/wp-content/themes/Divi/includes/builder/module/SignupItem.php on line 105. Can someone please help. :(

Comment: this file exsits in your folder `core\components\api\email\Fields.php:`

Comment: You are missing `ET_Core_API_Email_Fields` class or it's not loaded.

Comment: make sure all files are uploaded at live.

Comment: The error basically tells you what your problem is.

Comment: @Justinas The file exists. I think it is not loaded? Don't know to though. :(

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error when migrating a site with an older version of Divi - something like 3.1.1. I didn't get to the bottom of it, but activating a different theme (e.g. twentyseventeen), updating Divi, and then reactivating Divi fixed it. This is pretty straightforward if you have access to WP CLI.

Otherwise, I'd recommend upgrading Divi prior to starting the migration.